# How to enable drawing with in the bitmap on canvas android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

This is my requirement in my project,I am developing an application in android on canvas.The canvas covers the entire screen,I am drawing a bitmap on the canvas depends upon the aspect ration with the canvas.How to make restrict drawing outside of bitmap,Could any one help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Your onTouch should look something like this, yes?

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    x = (int) event.getRawX();
    y = (int) event.getRawY();
    /* other code */
}
```

Well, what you can do is restrict the onTouch method from doing anything when X and Y are not on the bitmap.

onTouch also returns a boolean if an onTouch has "really" consumed an event. In this case, you want to return true when the X, Y values are on the bitmap, but false when X, Y values are off the bitmap.

Also, if you want the event to act like they are lifting their finger up when they are off the bitmap, you can even call onTouch again passing in an event like:

```
this.onTouch(v, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
```

I hope this helps!